# FFmpeg Video Not Showing But I Hear the Sound

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` to convert my videos, and I thought everything was fine but I ran into a problem. When I go on my tablet to play the video, the video does not show but I hear the sound. Here's my code, thanks in advance.

```php
$vid = $request->file('video');
$filename = uniqid() . $vid->getClientOriginalName();

$request->video->move(public_path('/app'), $filename);
$name_file = uniqid() . 'intro_video.mp4';

$ffp = FFMpeg::open($filename)
    ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
        $filters->resize(new \FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(640, 640));
    })
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('s3')
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libfdk_aac', 'libx264'))
    ->save($name_file);

$imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($name_file);
```

Comment: Show the readout from `ffmpeg -i output`

Comment: @Gyan thanks for responding. I don't know about no ffmpeg -i output. Everything thing is on my website.

Comment: You don't have ssh access to the server? Can you provide the log from the ffmpeg process? You can add the `-report` option that will generate an overly verbose log file in the current directory. Can you provide the output file? The log will be the most useful and informative, but we can work with the other options.